# How can I select the top 10 largest numbers from a database column using SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a database table which contains a column that records page hits for every entry.

I want to select the top 5 most hit pages from the database, but can't seem to find the right method to do so using just SQL. In particular I'm looking for one which doesn't involve selecting every entry and scanning through it afterwards using PHP.

What's the best way to do this via SQL (if there is one)?

Thanks.

Comment: **WHAT** database? **Which** version??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
SELECT column1, column2, hit_pages,...
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY hit_pages DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Caveat: don't use select *, just select the columns you need.

Comment: @Jong - difficult to give a better example without provided table structure.

Comment: @eumiro Table structure is more or less irrelevant to Jong's point, especially considering OP's question. You should never ever be using `SELECT *` **unless you specifically need every single column** in the table.

Comment: LIMIT will not work in T-SQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645065/297358 located below for T-SQL syntax

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL> `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY hits DESC limit 5;`

In Oralce> `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY hits DESC where rownum <5;`

Comment: I think it should be ORDER BY hist DESC (not ASC)

Comment: @Jong - yeh, the dangers of talking on the phone and typing an answer revealed ;-)

Comment: Oracle note: it's important to put the WHERE ROWNUM clause after the ORDER BY clause.  Otherwise you are taking the first 5 rows in the table as nondeterministically selected by the database, then sorting them.

Comment: @Justin thanks - i never even thought to note that, its just one of those things that you "just do" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT TOP 10 price(column Name) from products(tablename) order by price desc;

Below is the output

```
price
263.5 
123.79 
97 
81 
62.5 
55 
53 
49.3 
46 
45.6
```

Answer (score 0):

for find 20th maximum value primary key with where condition:

```
  declare @max20Pk int=0;
  select @maxPk=min(Pk_Transaction) from(
  select top 20  Pk_Transaction from tblTransaction with(nolock)
  where  Fk_ChargeType in(2,3)
  order by Pk_Transaction desc
  ) as dtt
```