# sql select top 10 values from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called articles, each article has a rating value.
I want to select * from the ten articles with the highest rating.

something along these lines

```
    $query = "SELECT TOP 10 rating FROM articles ORDER BY rating DESC";
```

I am confused about the TOP 10 part, I would usualy have SELECT * FROM

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL syntax, I believe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql Each of the various SQL servers has varying syntax, which is one of the reasons an ORM is so handy.

Comment: possible of duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874731/how-can-i-select-the-top-10-largest-numbers-from-a-database-column-using-sql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` to do this

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 10";
```

[Documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php) here

Answer (score -1):

you can do so by folloing SQL Query

```
 SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY rating DECS LIMIT 10;
```